# Shell Script Mac: Loop through Directory and Remove String

Tags: macos, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to loop my project folder recursively, `grep` every PHP file and find any string that matches `xdebug_break();`.

Then I want to remove that `xdebug_break()` (I will accept replacing with a space as well).

Here's what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(find ../../Dev/projects/api -type f -name *.php)

for f in $FILES
do
    if grep -nr "xdebug_break();" $f
    then
        sed -e '/xdebug_break();/d' -i $f
        echo "xdebug_break(); has been deleted."
    fi
done
```

Everything works, except the replace part. I keep getting this error:

```
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

I do not care if its `sed` or `awk` or whatever (but I do use a mac).

Thanks,

***SOLUTION (FOR FUTURE READERS)***

Thanks for the help everyone (ESP @anubhava). This one line trick did it for me:

```
find ../../Dev/projects/api -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' '/xdebug_break();/d' {} +
```

Also you can do it by loop (if you really really want to) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(find ../../Dev/projects/api -type f -name *.php)

for f in $FILES
do
    if grep -nr "xdebug_break();" $f
    then
        sed -i '' '/xdebug_break();/d' "$f"
        echo "xdebug_break(); has been deleted."
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX, your `sed` command should be:

```
sed -i.bak '/xdebug_break();/d' "$f"
```

Here `.bak` is the name of extension to create a backup of input file in inline editing.

You can avoid loop and do it in one `find` like this:

```
find ../../Dev/projects/api -type f -name "*.php" \
             -exec sed -i.bak '/xdebug_break();/d' {} +
```

Comment: anyway to use sed without creating a .bak file? @anubhava

Comment: Yes, sure. You can use `sed -i '' '/xdebug_break();/d' "$f"`

Comment: One lines should be: `find ../../Dev/projects/api -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' '/xdebug_break();/d' {} +` OR else: ``find ../../Dev/projects/api -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '' '/xdebug_break();/d' {} \;``

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `find` and `sed`:

```
find Dev/projects/api -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i.bak '/xdebug_break();/d' {} \;
```